# mysql conditional queries

Tags: mysql, case, conditional-statements

I have 3 tables in a mysql database names Visits, Groups, Carers. 
A visit can be executed by a group or a carer, so in the Visit table I have a field carer mode, set to 1 if the visit is exectuted by a carer and set to 0 if executed by a group.

I need to build a statement that will retrieve either the group name or the carer name (depending on the value of carer_mode)

I realise the code below is incorrect but it might help to explain the logic I am trying to achieve:

```
SELECT CASE carer_mode
WHEN  '1' THEN (SELECT name FROM carers WHERE Carers.id = Visits.carer_id )
WHEN '0' THEN (SELECT name FROM groups WHERE Groups.id = Visits.carer_id )
END as carer_name
FROM `Visits`
```

I would appreciate any help on valid code that would help me achieve my objective

thanks

Kevin

Comment: Why do you think the code you provided is wrong?

Comment: @Icarus: Right, overlooked for something else. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine. Here's another way to achieve the same result:

```
    SELECT g.name
    FROM 
        Visits AS v
      JOIN
        Groups AS g
          ON g.id = v.carer_id
    WHERE v.carer_mode = 0
UNION ALL
    SELECT c.name
    FROM 
        Visits AS v
      JOIN
        Carers AS c
          ON c.id = v.carer_id
    WHERE v.carer_mode = 1
```

Comment: Im such a dope..! my code was me just trying to work out the logic and represent it in an SQL statement, I never even checked to see if it would work, it did! your answer is accepted for spotting this and adding an alternative method. Thanks

Comment: @Karolis should get the record for spotting it first.

Comment: His answer is in the form of a comment though, so I couldnt accept it. I upvoted instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
  select 
  case carer_mode when '1' then c.name 
  else g.name end as carer_name 
  from Carer c 
  left join Visits v on v.carer_id=c.carer_id 
  left join Groups g on g.carer_id=c.carer_id
```

Comment: To allow you getting credit, you are very close, but need to have the visit as the primary from, and carer is your left join...  both are joined by the VISIT.Carer_ID